# newcommand with argument and shell-escape/write18

Tags: macros, python, shell-escape

This example works with shell-escape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}
\begin{python}
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *
print "$" + latex(expand( (x+1)*(x-1) )) + "$"
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

A very primitive (not working) approach of putting the symbolic expansion in a newcommand is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\newcommand{\pyexpand}[1]{
\begin{python}
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *
print "$" + latex(expand( #1 )) + "$"
\end{python}
}
\begin{document}
\pyexpand{(x+5)*(x-5)}
\end{document}
```

Error: ! Use of \@python doesn't match its definition.

How to make this work?

Comment: My feeling is that the `python` environment is in the same class as `verbatin`, so it cannot appear as argument to another command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, sorry.

The `python` environment is defined to write its contents in an auxiliary file and in order to do this it performs `verbatim` trickery, which prevents it from being used as the argument to a command.

You can use PythonTeX, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{pythontexcustomcode}{py}
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *
\end{pythontexcustomcode}

\newcommand{\pyexpand}[1]{%
  $\py{latex(expand( #1 ))}$%
}

\begin{document}

\pyexpand{(x-1)*(x+1)}

\end{document}
```

This requires an intermediate run of `pythontex`.

[image]